# How to modify shared variables from %dopar% block?

Tags: r, multithreading

I'd like to employ multiple CPUs while computing in R. So far I've tried `foreach` approach. I know it may return the values I need, however, I wonder if I can somehow modify the shared variables directly.

This is an example of what I'd like to achieve - the `result` variable should have an increasing diagonal. Please note that this is an illustrative example - in reality I need to compute about a dozen of matrices of variable dimensions and parsing the output of `foreach` would be very difficult. The computation takes about an hour which is hardly debuggable.

```
library("doParallel")
library("foreach")

cluster <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cluster)

result = matrix(nrow=5, ncol=5)

foreach (i = 1:5)  %dopar% {
    result[[i, i]] <<- i
}
```

Could you please suggest what operator/function/package should I use in order to achieve such behavior, i.e. modifying the shared variables from some parallel block of code? Let's assume there are no collisions and/or race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I think `%dopar%` starts by sending a copy of the shared variable to each cluster-node. Which makes it basically impossible to change them unless you run `%dopar%` again.

If you need to compute several matrices you could compute one complete matrice on each cluster-node, so you don't have to share variables between cluster-nodes.

Comment: And don't you know about some other approach? E.g. not using `%dopar%` at all? Anyway thanks for prompt reply :)

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html shows many options how to do parallel computation in R. My 2 suggestions would be: 1. read/write data from a database and thereby access the same data in all cluster-nodes 2. use Hadoop/Spark